# How downgrade gcc in debian linux?

Tags: linux, gcc, debian

i'm learning linux kunnel programming. however, i faced problem that gcc version is too high to execute 2.4kunnel "make" command(make bzImage),  I try to find solution. but in debian case solution does not exist, just for ubuntu, centOs ect... please help me Or, link that about my problem.

P.S ) What i want version of gcc is 3.3 version, it doesn't work use command apt-get install gcc-3.3

Answer (score 0):

Why would you learn based on 2.4?

Your question is wrong anyway. You will likely need other old tools. The way to go is to download an entire debian system and chroot inside. This can be achieved with debootstrap.

However, as noted earlier, you should not stick to 2.4 in the first place.